# $.mobile.changePage don't work

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I use $.mobile.changePage to go to another page. It success but after few second the page automatically back to the first page. How can i solve this problem?
here my code

```
$("#frmLogin").on("submit", function(e){
var u = $("#username",this).val();
var p = $("#password",this).val();
if(u != '' && p != ''){
    if(window.method.login(u,p) == true){
        $.mobile.changePage("home.html");
    }else{  
             navigator.notification.alert("wrong combination");
}
}else{
 navigator.notification,alert("wrong");
}
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your code runs, the form is continuing with the standard submit process, which involves reloading the page.

To stop that happening, your event handler needs to call preventDefault or return false.